# Manual Date Filter in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am working on processing a very large data set using pandas into more manageable data frames. I have a loop that goes through and splits the data frame into smaller data frames based on a leading ID number, I then sort by the date column. However, I notice that after everything runs there are still some issues with dates not being sorted correctly. I want to create a manual filter that basically loops through the date column and checks to see if next date is greater or equal to the previous date. This ideally would eliminate issues where the date column may go something like (obviously in more of a data frame format):

[2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2017,2018,2018]

I am writing some code to take care of this however, I keep getting errors and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to go.

```
 for i in range(len(Rcols)):
        dfs[i] = data.filter(regex=f'{Rcols[i]}-')
        dfs[i]['Engine'] = data['Operation_ID:-PARAMETER_NAME:']
        dfs[i].set_index('Engine',inplace=True)
        dfs[i][f'{Rcols[i]}-DATE_TIME_START']=pd.to_datetime(dfs[i][f'{Rcols[i]}-DATE_TIME_START'],errors = 'ignore')
        dfs[i].sort_values(by=f'{Rcols[i]}-DATE_TIME_START',ascending = True ,inplace=True)


        for index, item in enumerate(dfs[i][f'{Rcols[i]}-DATE_TIME_START']): 
            if dfs[i][f'{Rcols[i]}-DATE_TIME_START'][index + 1] >= dfs[i][f'{Rcols[i]}-DATE_TIME_START'][index]:
                continue
            else:
                dfs[i].drop(dfs[i][index])
```

Where Rcols is just a list of the column header leading IDs. dfs is a large list of names that call pandas data frames.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't particularly "manual", but you can use [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html). Here's a *minimal* example, but the principle works equally well with a series of dates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Years': [2017,2017,2018,2018,2018,2017,2018,2018]})

mask = df['Years'].shift() > df['Years']
df = df[~mask]

print(df)

   Years
0   2017
1   2017
2   2018
3   2018
4   2018
6   2018
7   2018
```

Notice how the row with index 5 has been dropped since 2017 < 2018 (the row before). You can extend this for multiple columns via a `for` loop.

You should *under no circumstances* modify rows while you are iterating over them. This is spelt out in the docs for [`pd.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> You should **never modify** something you are iterating over. This is not
>   guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
>   iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
>   effect.

However, this becomes irrelevant when there is a vectorised solution available, as described above.